# Select dinamico en Laravel 5.6, nose carga el segundo select a pesar de que en la consola logro ver que se estan trayendo los datos

Tags: laravel, select

```
  $(function(){
    $("#user_select").on('change', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        var user_id=e.target.value;
        $.get('http://localhost/helpdesk/public/userasset/'+ user_id,function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#assetselect').empty();
            $('#assetselect').append('<option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-- ACTIVO --</option>');

            $.each(data,function (index,assetObj) {
                $('#assetselect').append('<option value="'+ assetObj.id+'">'+ assetObj.model +'</option>')

            })
        });
    });
});

vista

   <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control show-tick" data-live-search="true" name="user_id" id="user_select">
                                <option value="">-- USUARIO --</option>
                                @foreach($users   as $user)
                                    <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->first_name}} {{$user->last_name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control show-tick" name="asset_id" id="assetselect">
                                <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">-- Seleccione ACTIVO --</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Saludos bienvenida, explica mejor la pregunta, por ejemplo cual es el problema que tienes

Comment: Gracias, el problema es que he intentado de mil formas pero el segundo select que quiero cargar a partir de la selección del primero no se carga , y en la consola puedo ver que los datos son traidos de forma correcta pero el segundo select como si nada , me explico!!! si me puedes ayudar lo agradezco

Comment: Gracias, Estoy programando el Laravel 5.6 necesito hacer un select que cargue su información de acuerdo con un select anterior el problema es que he intentado de mil formas pero el segundo select que quiero cargar a partir de la selección del primero no se carga , y en la consola puedo ver que los datos son traidos de forma correcta pero el segundo select como si nada , me explico!!! si me puedes ayudar lo agradezco

Comment: @MarinesAcostaMartinez ¿Qué es lo que te imprime `data`?, ¿podrías agregarlo?

Comment: data es la que trae el arreglo con los activos del usuario seleccionado

Comment: 2) […]
​
0: Object { id: 8, number: 125, model: "ML2010", … }
​
1: Object { id: 9, number: 25418, model: "1254", … }
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []

Comment: @MarinesAcostaMartinez ¿Has comprobado que el `$.each` se esté ejecutando?

Comment: @MarinesAcostaMartinez Si pudieras agregar una captura de pantalla en tu pregunta de lo que te devuelve data, estaría muy bien, ya que probablemente no estés recorriendo adecuadamente el objeto

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez Hola Aarón me parece que no se esta ejecutando

Comment: @MarinesAcostaMartinez Si es posible que postees como te está llegando la variable `data` pero con una captura de pantalla sería de gran ayuda, lo más seguro es que no estés accediendo bien al array que trae los objetos y por ende no esté recorriendo nada.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas haciendo mal tu `$.each` puesto que lo estas llenando con `data` y el `$('#assetselect')` se debe llenar con la respuesta del `ajax`, ¿En que variable recibes la respuesta del ajax?

Comment: En el código viene claramente que la petición `get` está recibiendo como segundo parámetro la función callback con la variable `data` en ella.

Comment: Podría poner lo que le imprime la consola con la variable data, es posible que necesita hacer lo siguiente: `var nuevaData = JSON.parse(data);`, y posteriormente proseguir con el `$.each(nuevaData, function(k,v){ ... });`